# Добавление постов кастомного типа с помощью cron и ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

У меня есть задача в cron, которая парсит данные с одного сайта и переводит их в json. Парсер работает исправно. Я создал кастомный тип поста events2, определил для него поля, но почему-то при выполнении задачи я не наблюдаю этих постов в админке. А они точно должны быть.

```
  function parse_events() {

  //тут был парсинг данных

    foreach($events as $e) {
        add_post_wp($e['name'], $e['img'], $e['date']);
    }
}

function add_post_wp($post_title='', $image_url='', $post_date='')
{   
    $post_data = array(
        'post_title'    => $post_title,
        'post_type' => 'events2',
        'post_date'  => $post_date,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'ping_status' => 'closed', 
        'post_content' => $post_title
    );

    //Check this article in DB
    $post_id = get_page_by_title($post_title, OBJECT, 'events2');
    if($post_id->ID<1)
    {
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

        update_field('name', $post_title, $post_id);
        update_field('date', $post_date, $post_id);

        //Add img
        if((!empty($image_url)) && ($post_id > 0))
        {
            $attachment_id = Generate_Featured_Image( $image_url, $post_id  );
            update_field('image_id', $attachment_id, $post_id);
        }
        $result = array('post_id'=>$post_id,  'attachment_id'=>$attachment_id);
    }else
    {
        $result = array('post_id'=>'Exist');
    }
    return $result;
}  
//Add Attachment to Wordpress
function Generate_Featured_Image($image_url, $post_id)
{
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
    $filename = basename($image_url);
    if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))     $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
    else                                    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_data);
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
    $res1= wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    $res2= set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
    return  $res2;
}

add_action( 'scheduled_events_action', 'parse_events' );
if (!wp_next_scheduled( 'scheduled_events_action')) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'twicedaily', 'scheduled_events_action' );
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код прямо в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка у вас в функции `add_post_wp()`

Вы, очевидно, проверяете существование записи, пытаясь получить информацию о посте по его заголовку. И в случае неудачи создать пост с указанным заголовком. Но вот что вы делаете:

```
// получаете пост по заголовку    
$post_id = get_page_by_title($post_title, OBJECT, 'events2');
// предполагаете, что если пост не существует,
// то вам вернётся объект, содержащий данные об ID = -1 или 0, или что-то подобное
if ($post_id->ID < 1) {...}
```

Теперь обратимся к [документации](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/) функции `get_page_by_title()` и обнаружим, что в случае, когда запись с запрошенным заголовком не найдена, функция возвращает `null`, а не объект.

Следовательно, условие `$post_id->ID < 1` никогда не может быть выполнено и блок кода, отрабатывающий по этому условию, соответственно, тоже.
Перепишите эту часть кода, учитывая информацию из документации.